# Magento installation error on wamp n xamp server

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm getting error. I tried again and reinstalled too. My PHP server is on an updated version.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /var/www/......../httpdocs/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php on line 411

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the server requirements for installing Magento 2, it might be that your PHP version is not high enough

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your server does not meet Magento's minimum requirements. Here's an excerpt, or [see here for more details](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html):

> Requirements
>
> - Composer (latest stable version)
>
> Composer is required for developers who wish to contribute to the Magento 2 codebase or anyone who wishes to develop > Magento extensions
>
> Web servers
>
> - Apache 2.2 or 2.4
>
> In addition, the apache mod_rewrite module must be enabled. mod_rewrite enables the server to perform URL rewriting. For > more information, see our Apache documentation.
>
> - nginx 1.8 (or latest mainline version)
>
> Database
>
> - MySQL 5.6
> - MariaDB and Percona are compatible with Magento because we support MySQL 5.6 APIs.
>
> PHP
>
> - 5.6.x
> - 5.5.x, where x is 22 or greater
> - 7.0.2, 7.0.6–7.0.x
>
> There is a known PHP 7.0.5 issue that affects our code compiler; to avoid the issue, do not use PHP 7.0.5.
>
> Not supported:
>
> - PHP 7.1
> - PHP 5.4
>
> Required PHP extensions:
>
> - bc-math
> - curl
> - gd, ImageMagick 6.3.7 (or later) or both
> - intl
> - mbstring
> - mcrypt
> - mhash
> - openssl
> - PDO/MySQL
> - SimpleXML
> - soap
> - xml
> - xsl
> - zip